# User edited my answer and made it look wrong

Tags: support, edits, specific-edit

I posted an answer and a user edited it and now my answer has become wrong. Is it possible to revert my answer back to the one which I wrote?

Also, what steps does Stack Overflow take on users who tamper with other peoples' answers?

Comment: You can always rollback edits that were made on your own posts.

Comment: When I try to edit my answer back to how it was, the site says "This part of the code cannot be edited".

Comment: If it is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56379446/revisions) then someone already rolled it back for you.

Comment: Yes, because I have rollbacked it. Refresh the page and go to your answer again.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to improve it only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've rolled back that edit. It clearly seemed wrong. Editing code is often incorrect, since it deviates from the original poster's intent. It isn't even an edit that fixes a minor syntax error (e.g. a parenthesis)! It clearly deviated from your intent and was an attempt to comment.

The user seems new to the edit system—they have only just earnt the privilege to edit immediately other people posts. Don't worry too much about it—ping the editor in comments and roll back.

To roll back an edit, go to the revisions history by pressing "edited x time ago" and click the [rollback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFwEY.png) link on the revision you want to revert to. (I have done it for you in this case, so you don't need to do it now.)

Comment: Thank you double beep. I tried to reach him through comments but he didn't respond.

Comment: Actually I tried to skip a line that delete empty list and reduced the for loop iteration

Comment: @SmartManoj editing the behavior of code blocks is generally not accepted anywhere on SE. If you want to suggest an improvement, leave a comment or write your own answer.

Comment: That statement is too broad, @TheWanderer. It is acceptable, but you need to be *certain* and absolutely know what you're doing. The original poster always has final say, of course, via the rollback feature. This is the point of double-beep's answer.

Comment: @CodyGray that's why I said "generally." There are cases where it makes sense, but it usually doesn't.